# Remove duplicate words

Tags: powershell, distinct

I have a string with a few words:

```
$list1= "apple tree dog cat apple horse tree"
```

How I can delete duplicate word?

Comment: $list1 | Sort-Object | Get-Unique 
not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first have to **split** the string to receive a list of words. Using `Select -Unique` will remove all duplicates and finally to transform the list into a single string, you join them using `-join`:

```
($list1 -split ' ' | Select -Unique) -join ' '
```

**Output:**

```
apple tree dog cat horse
```